# Time-series data in PyTorch Geometric

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I have time-series graph data. I try to predict graph representation for the next time period. Is there any Graph Convolution to handle time-series data or should I use PyTorch Geometric Temporal instead?

Comment: What changes over time? Only the node attributes, or maybe the topology?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very flexible class called "MessagePassing" provided in torch_geometric, where you can build custom GNNs. Have a look at this:
https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_gnn.html